# EF & WCF error - SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Hi I have a simple wpf app setup to consume my test wcf service running in another project. The service retrieves a few rows from a sql compact 3.5 sdf attached to the wcf  service project using Entity Framework.

Im getting the "SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development." error on the 1st line of the of my object context class in the service project as soon as I try and run one of the services.

This error supposedly can be suppressed with "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);" in the global.asmx file. However this is not an asp.net project so no global.asmx.

Where should I put this line? or is SQL CE 3.5 not designed for EF and WCF?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the line as the first execution code. If it is a normal console/winform/wpf application, just put it in the first line of main() function in Porgram.cs file.

A better solution might be upgrade to [v4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2), which does not generate this error at all.

Comment: "Update to v4.0, which does not generate this error at all" doesn't seem to be true.  I'm using 4.0 and its generating this error

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but this line of code help me to resolve the issue:

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);
 }
```

in your Global.asax

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 is not supported with applications hosted under ASP.NET, use version 4.0 instead. It does not require this property to be set, and is tested and supported with ASP.NET