# C# " SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development."!

Tags: wcf, sql-server-ce

I have problems with a WCF Service in my program, when I launch the sql query, Visual Studio shows

> SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development.

I read that my problem was using SQL Server CE 3.5 but I downloaded 4.0 and change the "references" in my project, exactly `System.Data.SqlServerCe`. When I try again it shows again the error

What can I do? I'm trying to put this into code:

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Code that runs on application startup
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting",  true);
 }
```

But the error persist.

Comment: Looks like you are still using 3.5 somewhere!

Comment: Yes, i deleted SQLCe from Windows 7, and install 4.0 again, then deleted the database whit 3.5 and create againd in 4.0, and now works fine ;)

Comment: See this linke http://stackoverflow.com/a/42061373/1770868